# no package.json in React Component building problem

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I make a website using react, but some problem occurs
I  folks someone's project, and make own module by mimic another code in the different directory.

But after building, the only new component which I made does not work.
Difference point that there are no package.json in my own component, but other components have.

How I can figure out this problem?

[screenshot of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbx3q.png)

Comment: Can you be more clear about your problem? Add any piece of code, error stack trace, component code.

Comment: no package.json?  perhaps you mean no node_module? if that's the case, you need to run `npm install` or `yarn`

Comment: I build a project with yarn install.
After building,  packaje.json is made in other directory (original code).
But, in directory that I made, packaje.json does not maded